# Email client support for embedding flash links in HTML email?

Tags: flash, email

I have a Flash-based chart I would like to include in an email report. Will most popular email clients like Outlook, Thunderbird, Gmail, Hotmail - render the chart or will they block it for security purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Almost no e-mail clients will support this. I think Office 2003 and prior can be cajoled into supporting it, but it will involve security prompts and probably won't result in the best user experience. Outlook 2007 or any major web e-mail provider I know of won't support it at all.

I would stick to a static image or link to the flash in question.

Here's some detailed information: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1974/the-truth-about-1/

Basically in the best case it's going to be a horrible user experience, and most of the time it won't work at all.